# How to make a discord.py event delete any new threads created that don't match a specific requisite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I don't know if it's possible, but I needed something just like this, but for threads

```
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    if channel.name != "approved-channel-name":
        await channel.delete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do very similar - just use the [`on_thread_create`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_thread_create) event rather than `on_guild_channel_create` event. The parameter is a [`Thread`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Thread) object which also has a `name` attribute and a `delete` method.